# Swift Package Manager: dependency rules: "from" vs "upToNextMajor"

Tags: swift, version, versioning, swift-package-manager, swift-package

Let's consider a common format of listing a dependency inside the package:

```
.package(url: "ssh://git@bitbucket.org:firm/repo.git", from: "1.1.0"),
```

And this format:

```
.package(url: "ssh://git@bitbucket.org:firm/repo.git", .upToNextMajor("1.1.0"))
```

Are these declarations equivalent? Or will `from` declaration update even beyond the major version change, i.e. if `2.0.0` is available, it'll be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these declarations are absolutely equivalent:

```
.package(url: "ssh://git@bitbucket.org:firm/repo.git", from: "1.1.0"),
```

```
.package(url: "ssh://git@bitbucket.org:firm/repo.git", .upToNextMajor("1.1.0"))
```

And even in case of the `from` declaration the update to the next major version won't happen automatically and will require changing the major version to `2` or higher in the declaration.